# How to make you web application in Azure be accessible through https?

Tags: azure, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I applied for certificates for my domains. I received files with the following extensions:

- ca-bundle
- crt (multiple files)
- p7b

I would like to upload SSL certificates to Azure by installing the certificate. For that I need to upload pfx file that is not included. I read that I need to create a private key and then merge the certificates somehow in order to create one. Unfortunately, as a programmer, I do not understand what and where should be done. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to do it in the following way:

I downloaded openssl from here: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Two files are needed - the domain certificate and the private key. Once you have them you issue the following command:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out file.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt

You need to provide a password for the export. This will create a file.pfx file that you can upload to Azure using the same password. The next step is to add SSL bindings. For each domain you choose the certificate and create the binding. After ~2 minutes the https connection will be available for your domains.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this link here talks about the exact scenario you are talking about.

*"The question is, how do I convert the CRT file into a PFX file so that I can upload it to my Azure Web App?  Here are the steps I followed to convert a CRT into a PFX file:"*

- Open Certificate Manager for the Local Computer
- Import the Intermediate Certificate (.P7B file)
- Import the SSL certificate (.CRT file)
- Export the SSL certificate and its dependencies as a .PFX file

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/12/02/add-an-ssl-certificate-to-an-azure-web-app-crt-and-p7b/

Comment: I am following the steps, but at "Export the SSL certificate and its dependencies as a .PFX file" I am unable to select PFX (it's greyed out). I can only select two CERs and one P7B...Any ideas?

Comment: Wait a minute...that is how it needs to be done. You use the SSL and its dependences and then create your PFX file. You cannot select because you are trying to create it (as per the blog post)

So, simply give a new name for the 'new' PFX file you are creating and continue with what the blog post says.

Comment: I do not understand...How do I make sure that on "Figure 8" the following: "Personal Information Exchange - PKCS #12 (.PFX)" is not greyed out and can be selected?

Comment: You don't select it because, that is what you are trying to create :) You use the P7B and cers to create the PFX. Then, you use them in your deployment of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it using a Windows system.
More info can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/12/02/add-an-ssl-certificate-to-an-azure-web-app-crt-and-p7b/)